# Is Autopilot Openstack 16.04 available?

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot, conjure-up

I tried to build an openstack deployment from scratch starting with 7 physical servers and Ubuntu 16.04.  I've had no issues using 14.04 on the same setup.

After the initial setup in MAAS 2.0 beta3 (which is substantially different than 1.99) I had my machines in a ready state, installed openstack with apt-get.  When I go to run openstack-install, it complains that I don't have openstack installed, when I try to apt-get openstack again, it shows that I already have the most up to date version.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This is still an issue in 16.04 apparently.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/767588/is-the-openstack-cloud-installer-broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, you'll want to follow this bug for status of MAAS 2.0 and Juju 2.0 https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1564577

As for OpenStack on 16.04 you'll want to do:

```
sudo apt install conjure-up
conjure-up openstack
```

Comment: which is the situation now? is it possible to deploy Openstack Autopilot on MAAS 2.0 and JUJU 2.0? thanks

Answer (score 1):

finally that is arrived:
[official guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot)