# Is the Openstack Cloud Installer broken?

Tags: apt, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and am up to date.  When I follow the instructions here for a single machine installation:

[Openstack Single Installer Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html)

Here is the sequence:

- Add the PPA repo `apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable`
- Update the local package indexes `apt-get update`
- Install the Openstack Installer `apt-get install -y openstack`

Incredibly (possibly part of the problem...) after only 308MB of package and component downloads this completes successfully.  Unfortunately the next step fails:

`ubuntu@xenial-64-base:~$ openstack-install
The program 'openstack-install' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install openstack`

The suggestion to `apt install openstack` shows that it is already installed, and the latest version.  I can't tell for sure if this is a problem with the repo, the installer, or with the current Xenial updates having issues with something older in the ppa.  I am left with an `openstack` executable which takes me to a prompt but the `openstack-install` exec seems to be missing:

`ubuntu@xenial-64-base:~$ openstack
(openstack) install`

This is the definition of optimism...

`openstack: 'install' is not an openstack command. See 'openstack --help'.
Did you mean one of these?
  catalog list
  catalog show
  console log show
  console url show
(openstack) catalog list
Missing parameter(s): 
Set a username with --os-username, OS_USERNAME, or auth.username
Set an authentication URL, with --os-auth-url, OS_AUTH_URL or auth.auth_url
Set a scope, such as a project or domain, set a project scope with --os-project-name, OS_PROJECT_NAME or auth.project_name, set a domain scope with --os-domain-name, OS_DOMAIN_NAME or auth.domain_name`

Since it is complaining about not having an RC file we have the python clients installed but without a working installer nothing is configured.

According to Launchpad there have not been any commits since the release 7 weeks ago:

[Ubuntu Openstack Installer](https://launchpad.net/~cloud-installer/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+index?field.series_filter=utopic)

I can try manually performing the steps that `openstack-install` if I can figure out what they are.  [Openstack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot) is not an option since I don't have the hardware prerequisites sitting around, and ultimately the intent of this is to provide a single image for integrating Openstack test suites (Rally, Tempest, Browbeat, Mythos) for deployment to multiple Openstack deployments around the globe and a tiny footprint is required to make it attractive.

Is anyone else aware of this issue and has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: I ran into the same thing.  I reverted back to using 14.04.

Comment: Here is my original question > http://askubuntu.com/questions/764507/is-autopilot-openstack-16-04-available

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workaround from gangstaluv:

`sudo apt install conjure-up
conjure-up openstack`

[Original Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764507/is-autopilot-openstack-16-04-available)