# openstack installer missing on new install

Tags: 16.04, openstack

I just downloaded and install 16.04 latest, and run the openstack install steps, and get an error that openstack-install can't be found.  "command not found"

Is something missing in the install files?

when I run find, the file really doesn't exist on my computer.

Comment: Can you describe in detail the exact commands you tried?

Comment: I had the same problem, different command in 16.04.  See here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/764507/is-autopilot-openstack-16-04-available

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
sudo apt install conjure-up    
conjure-up openstack
```

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install conjure-up
```

Then disable IPv6:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd
```

Then run:

```
conjure-up openstack
```