# can't install Openstack on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server, maas, openstack

I am trying to install Openstack on Ubuntu server, this command doesn't work on version 16.04 . Does any one face the same problem ? what is the resolution please?

command:

sudo openstack-install

Comment: See here... http://askubuntu.com/questions/764507/is-autopilot-openstack-16-04-available

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
sudo apt install conjure-up    
conjure-up openstack
```

Comment: please add code formatting to your answer - this would make it better readable

Comment: @Phillip -Zyan K Lee- Stockmann Not bad advice to new users; but, you can edit the answer as well.

Comment: @Kevin Bowen I tried to, but only adding code formatting was not enough change. So I figured, teaching new users would be a good deed as well. ;-)