# install Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot on Ubuntu 16.04 using conjure-up command

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot using a IBM System x3560 M4 where is installed as Hypervisor VMware ESXi 6. I've installed MAAS with 2 net (public and private), deployed 6 vnode for openstack, where one of this one is in ready status to deploy landascape.

[image]

then add the ppa for openstack and use the command

**`$: conjure-up openstack`**

to begin the deploy

[image]
[image]
[image]

but in this step receive this error

[image]

I've found this link but it's unbelievable that Autopilot is not work on MAAS and JUJU 2.0.

https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/154

after to update of OS if I re-run that receive the following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maas-server field needs to be the MAAS server URL i.e. `http://IPAddress/MAAS/` and simply NOT the the IP/Hostname.

Also, if credentials are entered incorrectly ever, then `~/.local/share/juju/*.yaml` should be deleted/moved.

Comment: I've found this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/764507/is-autopilot-openstack-16-04-available, and at moment it's impossible to make the deploy of Openstack Autopilot with MAAS 2.0 and JUJU 2.0.